# RoR: JSON mapped :key => "value" – change all key names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

This is what I have:

```
def index
    @attachments = current_user.attachments.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render :json => @attachments.map { |o| { url: o.picture.thumb.url }}
      end
    end
  end
```

> => [{:**url**=>"/uploads/attachment/picture/7/thumb_df3c0c3c.jpg"},  {:**url**=>"/uploads/attachment/picture/12/thumb_dd7839ee.jpg"}, ... }]

How can I change the key from **:url** to **:thumb**?

```
=> [{:thumb=>"/uploads/attachment/picture/7/thumb_df3c0c3c.jpg"},
 {:thumb=>"/uploads/attachment/picture/12/thumb_dd7839ee.jpg"}, ... }]
```

This is the whole object after: *render :json => @attachments*

My goal: thumb: thumb: "/uploads/attach..."

[image: nested object json]

Background: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/image-manager

I use the gem carrierwave to create a thumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change key from "url" to "thumb"

```
render :json => @attachments.map { |o| { **thumb: o.picture.thumb.url** }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
response.map! { |urls| { :thumb =>  urls[:url] }  }
```